With in Cypher query confusion
Can someone please describe the chaining logic in this Cypher code:
This code is provided in the graph academy lessons, and it converts the language property of node Movie into a separate node.
MATCH (m:Movie)
UNWIND m.languages AS language
WITH  language, collect(m) AS movies
MERGE (l:Language {name:language})
WITH l, movies
UNWIND movies AS m
WITH l,m
MERGE (m)-[:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l);
MATCH (m:Movie)
SET m.languages = null

Particularly, this line is very mysterious to me: MERGE (m)-[:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l); how does Cypher remembers that mapping of which movie mapping to which language, because we're doing a lot of with there and unwinding till we get to WITH l,m where we have l as the language added nodes and m as the movies list unwind.
Can you either help with some viz or direct me to understand the inner working of this, because it's not intuitive at all.
I tried to read about the WITH clause, and I understand that it does the GROUP BY equivalent of SQL, but still far away from the clear picture of the inner process in Cypher.

An illustration may be helpful.
If we run this query:
MATCH (m:Movie)
UNWIND m.languages AS language
WITH language, collect(m) AS movies
MERGE (l:Language {name:language})
WITH l, movies
UNWIND movies AS m
WITH l, m
MERGE (m)-[r:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l);

And the DB has these 3 movies:
(m1:Movie {id: 'm1', languages: ['en']})
(m2:Movie {id: 'm2', languages: ['es', 'fr', 'en']})
(m3:Movie {id: 'm3', languages: ['fr', 'es']})

Here are the data rows resulting from each clause of the query (with variable names in each heading). Unquoted items in a row are either nodes or relationships; I take the liberty of using hopefully-understandable names for them.
MATCH (m:Movie)

     m
    --
    m1
    m2
    m3

UNWIND m.languages AS language

     m  language
    --  --------
    m1  'en'
    m2  'es'
    m2  'fr'
    m2  'en'
    m3  'fr'
    m3  'es'

WITH language, collect(m) AS movies

    language    movies
    --------  --------
    'en'      [m1, m2]
    'es'      [m2, m3]
    'fr'      [m2, m3]

MERGE (l:Language {name:language})

    language    movies   l
    --------  --------  --
    'en'      [m1, m2]  en
    'es'      [m2, m3]  es
    'fr'      [m2, m3]  fr

WITH l, movies

     l    movies
    --  --------
    en  [m1, m2]
    es  [m2, m3]
    fr  [m2, m3]

UNWIND movies AS m

     l    movies   m
    --  --------  --
    en  [m1, m2]  m1
    en  [m1, m2]  m2
    es  [m2, m3]  m2
    es  [m2, m3]  m3
    fr  [m2, m3]  m2
    fr  [m2, m3]  m3

WITH l, m

     l   m
    --  --
    en  m1
    en  m2
    es  m2
    es  m3
    fr  m2
    fr  m3

MERGE (m)-[r:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l);

     l   m      r
    --  --  -----
    en  m1  r1_en
    en  m2  r2_en
    es  m2  r2_es
    es  m3  r3_es
    fr  m2  r2_fr
    fr  m3  r3_fr


A clear breakdown, clean and easy to follow. One little bit of supplemental context to the OP: the rows/records generated are important, because Cypher operators generate and update these rows, which maintain the context of the data being processed as the query executes. Also, most Cypher operators execute per row. So when MERGE (m)-[r:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l) executes, it executes on each incoming row, where each row has its own l and m references, generated from the operations earlier in the query.

Let's take this explanation line by line to see where you're getting lost and see if we can add some clarification.  Please comment if any part of the query remains unclear

MATCH (m:Movie)
get all the nodes that have the Movie label

UNWIND m.languages AS language
the node has a .languages property that is an array of strings.  Each string represents a language that the movie is available in. UNWIND is basically like procedural foreach, where the subsequent statements are interpreted from within the iterator block - so instead of having a list of languages, you get a single language and the following statements distribute over the list.

WITH  language, collect(m) AS movies
select each language string paired with the list of each movie node that is available in the language

MERGE (l:Language {name:language})
get the node with the Language label.  If it doesn't exist yet, create it.

WITH l, movies Select each language node paired with the list of each movie node that is available in the language

UNWIND movies AS m foreach movie node in the list of movie nodes that are available in the language represented by the language node

WITH l,m Select the language node paired with the movie node.  This is similar to a procedural nested foreach loop, as in foreach (l in languages) { foreach (m in movies) { ... } }, except that only the pairs of languages and movies that are associated by a movie's languages property are considered

MERGE (m)-[:IN_LANGUAGE]->(l) get the IN_LANGUAGE edge between each movie and language where the name of the language is in the movie's languages list*

; end the first statement.  At this point, you've created an edge from each movie to each language in the movie's languages array

MATCH (m:Movie) get every movie node

SET m.languages = null delete the languages property, which is reasonable since we now have a relationship to a language node that contains the same information as is in the deleted list property



Thanks, but this is select each language string paired with the list of each movie node that is available in the language not easy to understand, so the code behind for some reason knows the relationship between language and movie? if m.language = [1,2,3] surely WITH  language, collect(m) AS movies will do the cross join in sql. Because 1 has no relationship with Movies

No.


If m.language = [1,2,3] for a given (m:Movie) then you are defining 1 as having a relationship with that particular movie represented by m.  The relationship exists by virtue of 1 being a member of the collection in the language property of the movie node.


This is not a cross-join / cartesian product, because ordered pairs of languages and movies where there is no association will not appear in the results.  Imagine (m1 :Movie { languages: [1,2,3] }) and (m2 :Movie { languages: [3,4] }).  The results would include: {(1,[m1]),(2,[m1]),(3,[m1,m2]),(4,m2)}



It may be instructive to test out components of the query individually so you can see the intermediate results.  Anything that can appear in a WITH clause could instead appear in a RETURN clause with the prior part of the query terminating at that point.
